# Extracting IMF-data

Tags: r

I try to download the "World Gross domestic product, current prices" using the IMFdata-API. If I use this query:

```
library(IMFData)
databaseID <- 'IFS'
startdate = '2001-01-01'
enddate = '2016-12-31'
checkquery = TRUE
queryfilter <- list(CL_FREA="", CL_AREA_IFS="W0", CL_INDICATOR_IFS="NGDP_USD")
W0.NGDP.query <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, checkquery)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="u
                 (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning message:
JSON string contains (illegal) UTF8 byte-order-mark!
```

How can I fix this? Is there a better way using Quandl, etc.?